# APCu: Cannot call key() on invalid iterator

Tags: php, docker, apc, ddev, apcu

I'm working on an older version of [ILIAS 5.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILIAS) in an DDEV (Docker) development environment. It is a **L**earning **M**anagement **S**ystem written in PHP. The runtime environment consists of:

- GNU/Linux Debian 10 Buster
- PHP 7.3
- MariaDB 10.3

Currently I stumbled over an error regarding the `APCUIterator` which I don't know how to handle. Regarding the while-clause, where the `key()`-method is being called on the iterator

```php
    /**
     * @param bool $complete
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function flush($complete = false)
    {
        if ($complete) {
            return apcu_clear_cache();
        }

        $key_prefix = $this->returnKey('');
        $apcu_iterator = new APCUIterator();
        $apcu_iterator->rewind();
        while ($current_key = $apcu_iterator->key()) {
            // "begins with"
            if (substr($current_key, 0, strlen($key_prefix)) === $key_prefix) {
                $this->delete($current_key);
            }
            $apcu_iterator->next();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

the error message says: *Cannot call key() on invalid iterator*—Inside the container I can reproduce the error with the following extracted snippet

```php
<?php
$iterator = new APCUIterator();
$iterator->key();
# Nothing else matters
```

and the resulting error renders like the following screenshot in the browser

[image]

My best guess is that there is something missing inside the container. Either a dependency or a configuration. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Here follows the APC configuration related `ddev php -i | grep -i apc` output.

```
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/25-apcu_bc.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/enableapcu.ini,
apc
APC Compatibility => 1.0.5
apcu
APCu Support => Enabled
APCu Debugging => Disabled
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.enable_cli => On => On
apc.enabled => On => On
apc.entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.mmap_file_mask => no value => no value
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.serializer => php => php
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 32M => 32M
apc.slam_defense => Off => Off
apc.smart => 0 => 0
apc.ttl => 0 => 0
apc.use_request_time => Off => Off
igbinary APCu serializer ABI => 0
```

**EDIT 2:** Here follows the APC configuration related `php -i | grep -i apc` output from the native staging system (not Docker) based on Debian with Apache web server.

```
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini,
apcu
APCu Support => Disabled
APCu Debugging => Disabled
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.enable_cli => Off => Off
apc.enabled => On => On
apc.entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.mmap_file_mask => no value => no value
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.serializer => php => php
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 32M => 32M
apc.slam_defense => Off => Off
apc.smart => 0 => 0
apc.ttl => 0 => 0
apc.use_request_time => On => On
```

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: DDEV includes php-apcu in the container, so I doubt there's anything else you need there. But just for grins, try php7.2 and php7.4. Just change the ddev config and `ddev restart`. `ddev php -i` will show you the current configuration and what modules are enabled, etc.

Comment: I turned the screenshot code into text.

Comment: @rfay Unfortunately, changing PHP to version 7.2 or 7.4 has not changed the behavior. I added the APC related configuration to my question.

Comment: Looks like APCu is turned off? Why don't you try enabling it in your ini. Add to your project `.ddev/php/enableapcu.ini`:
`apc.enable_cli=1`

Comment: I just set `apc.enable_cli=1` and now it is turned on. Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. I guess `apc.enable_cli` ist for the PHP CLI interpreter? The other one `apc.enabled`was turned on already.

Comment: I expect that's correct. I think you'll just have to figure out what's wrong with your code. I think if you install PHP on any system with the default configuration you'll have the same problem.

Comment: I still think it is not the code but the environment, producing the error. The very same code is working just fine in an other (no Docker) system. I added EDIT 2 to show the configuration differences regarding APC. My first clue is, that DDEV has both apc + apcu configured. Maybe this might be a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same issue on `$apcu->current()`.

One way to avoid this is to try `$apcu->valid()`, which should return `true`:

```php
$apcu_iterator = new APCUIterator();
if ($apcu_iterator->valid()) {
 // do stuff on iterator
}
```

It seems that when the iterator didn't found any valid key (either there's nothing stored, or you filtered it and no key matches), it returns an invalid iterator:

```php
$apc = new APCUIterator();
var_dump($apc->getTotalCount());
var_dump($apc->valid());
```

With keys:

```
int(5)
bool(true)
```

Without valid keys:

```
int(0)
bool(false)
```

So you can use either `->valid()` or check `->getTotalCount()` before using the iterator.